# Error adding Crond "cronie" to yocto build

Tags: cron, yocto

I am trying to add crond to a yocto build, I added the following line to local.conf

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = "cronie "
```

and attempted to build the image,

Error messages are as follows:

```
ERROR: karo-image-userfs-1.0-r0 do_rootfs: Postinstall scriptlets of ['busybox'] have failed. If the intention is to defer them to first boot,
then please place them into pkg_postinst_ontarget_${PN} ().
Deferring to first boot via 'exit 1' is no longer supported.
Details of the failure are in /home/chadg/karo-new/build-txmp-1530/tmp/work/txmp_1530-poky-linux-gnueabi/karo-image-userfs/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_rootfs.
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/chadg/karo-new/build-txmp-1530/tmp/work/txmp_1530-poky-linux-gnueabi/karo-image-userfs/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_rootfs.2691032
ERROR: Task (/home/chadg/karo-new/layers/meta-karo-distro/recipes-karo/images/karo-image-userfs.bb:do_rootfs) failed with exit code '1'
```

I did a little bit a googling on the error code, but didnt find anything specific I could try.

Comment: It will not be the answer, but should the space not be before cronie if you do a _append.  And after if you do a prepend?

Answer (score 0):

I face this issue when I append the LTP to root fs, and I finally figure out the root cause.
The cronie bitbake will install the crond binary to the /usr/sbin, which leads to the busybox linking operation failure for crond in the do_rootfs stage.

R
BC